# Select faces by shader?

Tags: python, materials, node-editor, shaders

Say I have a Mix Shader in a node setup.

Say I have a Wave Texture connected to the 'fac' input on this said Mix Shader.

I'm assuming that this functionality isn't built into Blender, so how can I use Python to select the faces that are a certain shader from the Mix Shader?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be more precise? Materials are assigned to faces, but shading properties belongs to the surface points. Usually shaders are masked out with the input of the Mix shader, in your case the Wave texture.

Comment: @Carlo I don't know exactly what you're asking me to say.

Comment: Just to add more information about what you would like to achieve, because at the moment I cannot figure it out clearly. Think about a single-quad plane with a wave texture: I can see black and white areas, but the truth is that the face is only one. You would not be able to select non-existing geometry.

Comment: @Carlo Yes, but if the plane were subdivided, would there be a way to select the vertices that are expressly in the white areas, for example?